# No qualifying bean of type while trying to use @Autowired

Tags: java, spring, autowired

This is the structure of the project:

```
com
    ->services
        ->dal
            ->dao
```

This is the classes:

```
package com.services.dal.dao;
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    @Component
    public class PSDAO extends BaseDAO<ParkingSpots, ObjectId> implements IPSDAO{

    public PSDAO(Class<ParkingSpots> entityClass, MongoClient mongoClient, Morphia morphia,
            String datasource) {
        super(entityClass, mongoClient, morphia, datasource);
    }
}
```

Interface:

```
package com.services.dal.dao;
public interface IPSDAO extends IBaseCRUD{

}
```

Test:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = "classpath:**/applicationContext.xml")
public class PSDAOTest {

    @Autowired
    IPSDAO psDAO;
}
```

XML:

```
<bean class="com.services.dal.dao.PSDAO" id="PSDAO">
        <constructor-arg ref="morphia" index="0" />
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo" index="1" />
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDb" index="2" />
</bean>
```

was trying as well to switch it to :

```
<bean class="com.services.dal.dao.IPSDAO" id="PSDAO">
        <constructor-arg ref="morphia" index="0" />
        <constructor-arg ref="mongo" index="1" />
        <constructor-arg ref="mongoDb" index="2" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Why do you have an `@Component` annotation _and_ a bean definition on your `applicationcontext.xml`? This is very confused and not entirely surprising that it isn't working as you expect...

Comment: Your constructor has 4 arguments. You're passing only 3, and not in the correct order...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that spring did not recognize that he cannot find the file classpath:**/applicationContext.xml , i was expected that in that case there will be file not found exception.

By changeing the it to `file:../../../<explicit path>` everything works just fine.